# event.button not working properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm using JQuery event object's button property to get whether the left button of the mouse was clicked during a mouseout event:

```
$("#foo").on("mouseout", function(event){
   if (event.button === "0"){
      // do code
   }
});
```

According to the specification button property gets the string value "0" if the left button was clicked, and it gets the value "-1" if none of the buttons.

My problem is that in Chrome (I haven't tried it on other browser yet) I get the value "0" whether left button is being clicked or none of the buttons are being clicked. If I clicked the right button, I get the proper value ("2") as in the specification. So I only have problem if none of the buttons are being clicked (it should give the "-1" value, but it gives the "0" value).

Do you have any clue?

I know there is a buttons (plural!) property two, but I use TypeScript and it cannot recognize this proprety for JQueryEventObject class. However in JavaScript buttons property works well for me.

Comment: if i rightclick while leaving an object i trigger the contextmenu event. i'd rather listen to click/contextmenu event to determine if a right or left click has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm using JQuery event object's button property to get whether the left button of the mouse was clicked during a mouseout event.*

But you are using a mouse event which is not in the list *mouseout*, but docs @ MDN says this:

> The MouseEvent interface represents events that occur due to the user interacting with a pointing device (such as a mouse). Common events using this interface include **click, dblclick, mouseup, mousedown**.

Comment: maybe mouseout is not a common event using the MouseEvent interface, but it can use it according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout

Comment: But this event does not provide you the `button` property from the event object i guess.

Comment: according to MDN it has the button property, it's in the property list (developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout), and it is available and works fine except for the issue reported above